# array of matrices numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix

I need to make an array of matrices in numpy. This is so I can treat them as scalars and dot this with another array, like so:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [A,B,C] #A, B, and C are matrices

result = a.dot(b) #1A + 2B + 3C
```

Or similarly with a matrix M such that:

```
M.dot(b) -> another array of matrices
```

Is there a way of doing this? Currently, every array-like thing gets subsumed into the numpy array outside that allows `.dot()` in the first place. So, if `A`, `B`, and `C` were 3x3 matrices, `a` would be:

```
a.shape -> (3,3,3) #matrices absorbed into array
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want `M.dot(b)` to equal?

Comment: Matrix `M` is any matrix of coefficients. `M.dot(b)` would give another transformed array of matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
X= np.ones((3,3))
Y= np.ones((3,3))
Z= np.ones((3,3))
b = np.array([X,Y,Z], dtype=object)
print a.dot(b)
```

results in:

```
[[6.0 6.0 6.0]
 [6.0 6.0 6.0]
 [6.0 6.0 6.0]]
```

Remember that the length of array of scalars must be of the same size of matrices (in this case matrices 3x3, so you need an array of length 3)

Comment: Ok. What is `dtype=object`? I don't understand how `1 * b` would give that result.

Comment: dtype=object
tells numpy that elements of array are objects instead of numbers (e.g., np.float32). 1*b is scalar by vector, so multiply scalar by every matrix.
I updated the solution in the post, now it is working as you expect.

Comment: @arkaeologic if the answer is ok for you accept it.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot. it was the `dtype=object` that did it.